# Question about topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let's mark the standard topological space on $\mathbb{R}$ with $\tau$.
We'll define new topology on $\mathbb{R}$, $\tau_l$ with the following base:
$B_l = \{[a,b)|a,b \in \mathbb{R},a<b\}$

I have to prove that a function $f:(\mathbb{R}_l,\tau_l)\to(\mathbb{R},\tau) $ is continuos iff $f$ is continuos from the right in the normal calculus meaning.

So one direction is relatively easy (topological continuousness -> calculus continuousness) but the other one i'm having a hard time to prove.

Comment: Hint: There is a countable basis of open sets.

Comment: Also in calculus I can think of several characterisations of continuity from the right. Which one are you using?

Comment: The one with $\epsilon$ and $\delta$:
$0<x-x_0<\delta \to |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you already have the theorem that a map between topological spaces is continuous if and only if it is continuous in each point.

So fix an arbitrary $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, then you have to show that $f \colon (\mathbb{R},\tau_l) \to (\mathbb{R},\tau)$ is continuous in $x_0$ if and only if $f$ is right-continuous in $x_0$ in the calculus sense.

$f \colon (\mathbb{R},\tau_l) \to (\mathbb{R},\tau)$ is continuous in $x_0$ if and only if for every $\tau$-neighbourhood $V$ of $f(x_0)$, there is a $\tau_l$-neighbourhood $U$ of $x_0$ with $f(U) \subset V$. It is sufficient to consider some fixed neighbourhood bases of $x_0$ resp. $f(x_0)$. If you choose the right neighbourhood bases, the equality of the conditions becomes obvious.